# Angular 5 RxJS Subscription Timing Issue

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

New to Angular RxJS observables and am having an issue with timing and how to approach the following scenario.

I am using RxJS: 5.5.2 and Angular 5.2.1

I have the following code:

```
public checkRecType(myrec: string) {
  this.myService.getRecType(myrec).subscribe(
     result => {
       if (result) {
          this.recType = true;
       } else {
          this.recType = false;
       }
     });
 } 

public isRecord = (rc: any): boolean => {
  this.checkRecType(rc);
  return (_.find(this.record, {'name': rc}) && this.type); 
}
```

The issue I am having is that when I do the check for `isRecord` that calls checkRecType, the value of `this.type` from my subscription above does not seem to return in time to satisfy my whole boolean return.

How can I approach this in Angular 5? I need to ensure that a boolean is returned for the above processing and that `this.type` is available when isRecord returns its result.

Comment: If `getRecType` is asynchronous, `isRecord` will need to be asynchronous, too, and should return an observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that in such way:

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map"
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable"

public checkRecType(myrec: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.myService.getRecType(myrec).map(
     result => {
       if (result) {
          this.recType = true;
       } else {
          this.recType = false;
       }
       return this.recType; 
// or instead you could (_.find(this.record, {'name': rc}) && this.recType); 
     });
 } 

public isRecord = (rc: any) => {
  this.checkRecType(rc).map(res =>
    (_.find(this.record, {'name': rc}) && res); 
  ).subscribe();
}
```

Instead of subscribing you `map` through results in `getRecType` and it returns you wither true or false. Now in `isRecord` you also map returning value and use it in any function you want. Finally you subscribe after all combinations are placed. In such way you tell Rxjs how to handle the stream.

That is just one simple possible way. I bet there are many many other ways.

Using Rxjs6 is very similar. Instead of `.map(` you do `.pipe(map(`. `pipe` is a lettable operator, it helps to chain operators easier. Also using them you reduce the final bundle size of the application.

Comment: @msanford, thanks I'll add. I dodnt used lettable operators as I dont know which version OP uses, but will add that too

Comment: Yes indeed it maintains the same syntax as OP! It was merely a note for other readers in the community, not necessarily something 'wrong' with your answer :)

Comment: using rxjs: 5.5.2 and angular 5.2.1

Comment: @tonyf, so my post is the syntax you should use. Note - you could still use Rxjs6 package, just need to add one dependency `rxjs-compat`. I would advice this approach as bundle size will be reduced

Comment: @yourFather to use your map syntax as I am not familiar with this, do I need to import any rxjs operator(s)? Thanks.

Comment: @tonyf yes you must. This should be it - `import "rxjs/add/operator/map";`

Comment: @yourFather do I need the semicolon at the end of (_.find(this.record, {'name': rc}) && res);  ?

Comment: @yourFather Furthermore, I seem to be getting the following message - unsure if error: "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value." Any ideas pls?

Comment: @yourFather apologies but also getting Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void'

Comment: @tonyf you also should inform Typescript about the types - `checkRecType(myrec: string): Observable<any>` (also need to import Observable - `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable` )

Comment: @yourFather are you able to please update your code to reflect this. I would really appreciate it as I am down to these two errors. thanks.

Comment: @yourFather seems like I need to add a return this.myService.getRecType(myrec).map( but unfortunately I'm not getting a result back from checkRecType, within isRecord. The value of res is undefined. Unsure why?

Comment: @yourFather seem to get result now but as initially stated, is there a way I can return a boolean for public isRecord = (rc: any): boolean => { as I think you can't do a subscribe for a boolean return?

Comment: @tonyf, hm.  Not sure why that happens. I edited again to be sure that  the correct true or false is returned.

Comment: @yourFather sorry. I was getting the correct result but do I need to also add a return this.checkRecType(rc).map(res => within isRecord as well?

Comment: @tonyf - you can return it in `.subscribe(bool => this.someVal =  bool);`

Comment: @yourFather really appreciate your help. if this .subscribe(bool => return bool); actually returns a boolean value then I must have an issue somewhere else.

Comment: @tonyf you can `.map(res => console.log(res))` - if its a boolean, problem is bellow. And you better do `.subscribe(bool => this.someVal = bool);` actually I never did `.subscribe(bool => bool);` but IMO it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can't just go from async to sync like that. If you're using async methods, the method using it has to be async as well.

So, something like this (code not verified):

```
  public getRecType(myRec: string): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.myService.getRecType(myrec).map(recType => !!recType);
  }

  public isRecord(rc: any): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.getRecType().map(recType => {
        _.find(this.record, { name: rc }) && this.type
      });
  }
```

Edit: works only if `_.find()` is synchronous. If not, you will have to, again, use Observables and probably `combineLatest` the two streams.